# TypeORM - how to append object to array with Postgres?

Tags: arrays, typescript, database, postgresql, typeorm

I've got db architecture placed on Postgres and a problem with column with `json` type like below:

```
    @Column({
        type: 'jsonb',
        nullable: false,
        default: []
    })
    users: Array<User>
```

when I try to push new element to this array like here:

```
        await this.entityManager.getRepository(Project)
          .createQueryBuilder('project')
          .update()
          .set({
            users: () => `array_append('users', ${JSON.stringify({ name: user.firstname })}::jsonb)`
          }).execute();
```

compilator throw me this error:

```
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "{"
```

SQL Query: `` query: `UPDATE "project" SET "users" = array_append('deployments', {"name":"Andrzej"}::jsonb) WHERE project.id = $3 ``

can someone tell me how to properly push new element to array in Postgres? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

As per error: You need to single quote the json.

**After fixing your code will look like**:

```
await this.entityManager.getRepository(Project)
      .createQueryBuilder('project')
      .update()
      .set({
        users: () => `array_append('users', '${JSON.stringify({ name: user.firstname })}'::jsonb)`
      }).execute();
```

**And your SQL query will look like this:**

```
UPDATE "project" SET "users" = array_append('deployments', '{"name":"Andrzej"}'::jsonb) WHERE project.id = 3
```